# How to pass XCode variable to local HTML in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, xcode, uiwebview

How to pass XCode variable to local HTML in UIWebview.

I have a UIWebView that loads a local HTML file from the resources folder.
Now, this HTML file has Javascript inside it.

My question is, is there a way to pass a XCode variable to the HTML file with a Button and Textfield, that gets loaded inside the UIWebView which I can pass to the Javascript function in the HTML.

Thanks a lot for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `NSString`'s **`stringWithFormat:`**?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<title>%@</title>",theTitle.text];
```

Then you can just load the HTML string into your webView.

Or **`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:`**

```
[myHTMLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{{some.property}}" withString:lblSomeProperty.text]
```

And in your Javascript page you would place **{{some.property}}** where you want to insert something.